# Keyboard malfunction and USB issue

Tags: usb, keyboard, motherboard

Last night I spilled water on my keyboard, it stopped working so I replaced it. The new keyboard is malfunctioning i.e. if I type 'b' I get 'bn'. Some keys do not work and some trigger enter. I tried multiple ports with no luck.

As well as this I'm getting 200kbs speeds on copying files from an external hdd when previously I may get 2mbs

I think I may have damaged the motherboard but not sure how any advice is appreciated

The original keyboard was texet, the new Polaroid. My brother has the same keyboard no issues (its brand new). Running Windows 7, AMD A8-3870 APU 4 CPUS ~3.0 GHz, GwForce GTX 670, 8GB DDR3. ASUS motherboard but unsure on the model
(Typing with onscreen keyboard which is frustrating)

Comment: The original was texet, the new Polaroid. My brother has the same keyboard no issues (its brand new). Running Windows 7, AMD A8-3870 APU 4 CPUS ~3.0 GHz, GwForce GTX 670, 8GB DDR3. ASUS motherboard but unsure on the model. Thanks

Comment: Will do, didn't originally because the onscreen keyboard is so slow. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried unplugging it and testing with your brother's keyboard?

Comment: My Dad is coming over tomorrow to try a new keyboard but how slow the external hdd is operating I'm not expecting any results

Comment: Try a different USB port connected to a different USB header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new installation may have not configured drivers correctly. 
Try deleate drivers for those hardwear and restart. 
next you may also try free tools like SlimDrivers to check and update your hardware / software configurations.

references:

http://www.escotal.com/IRQ.html

http://smallbusiness.chron.com/repair-windows-keyboard-driver-46858.html

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/devices-drivers-help#hardware-drivers-help=windows-vista&v1h=win8tab1